# Conditional formatting on Calendar view is not showing all choices in a column as values

Tags: custom-list, view-formatting, calendar-view

I have a list that includes a "Category" column, which consists of several color choices. When I try to apply conditional formatting to this list in Calendar view, it only shows me the "Orange" option to select as a value, even though the rows in my list have other colors selected in that column.

Here is a snip of the column in my list showing other selections besides "Orange":

[image: Here is a snip of the column in my list showing other selections besides "Orange"]

and here is the conditional formatting tab in Calendar view:

[image: and here is the conditional formatting tab in Calendar view:]

Also, for clarification, I already set it up to show the "Category" column as an option in conditional formatting using the "Add or Remove Fields" option. I am just having trouble accessing the other values besides "Orange"

Thanks!

UPDATE: I've now noticed that changing the color of one specific row changes the option that I have in Conditional Formatting. When I change that row from Orange to Blue or Green or Purple, the option that appears in the Conditional Formatting dropdown switches to whichever color is selected for that row.

Comment: Do these values still exist (blue, green)? Can you change Blue to Green? Do you maybe have 2 fields called Category?

Comment: Yes, those values still exist, and yes, I am able to change blue to green. I did check to see if I had more than one field called Category, but I only see one. I did also notice that changing the color of one specific row changes the option that I have in Conditional Formatting. When I change that row from Orange to Blue or Green or Purple, the option that appears in the Conditional Formatting dropdown switches to whichever color is selected for that row. Updating the main post with this info.